# withdraw function for withdraw ethereum token from a contract is behaving weird

Tags: solidity, ganache, truffle-test, balances

I copy a withdrawal function from the solidity documentation and added it to my contract

```
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
      uint256 ownerBalance = address(this).balance;
      require(ownerBalance > 0, "ERRFUN");
      payable(owner()).transfer(ownerBalance);
      emit ChangeEtherBalance(ownerBalance);
    }
```

Obs. My contract use:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

The problem is that while testing I found out that after the function's call the balance of the contract is zero, however, the balance of the owner is lower than the balance before. Here is the code of my test and the print of the console commands:

```
    describe('Test withdraw() method. Sucess', () => {
    it('withdraw success', async function () {
        const ownerBalanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(owner);
        const vendorBalanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.managementCenter.address);
        console.log("owner init Balance",ownerBalanceBefore) //owner init Balance 995570313620188160000
        console.log("vendor init Balance", vendorBalanceBefore) //vendor init Balance 257200000000000
        // withdraw operation
        const txWithdraw = await this.managementCenter.withdraw({ from: owner });

        // Check that the Vendor's balance has 0 eth
        const vendorFinalBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.managementCenter.address);
        expect(vendorFinalBalance).to.be.bignumber.equal(new BN(0));

        const ownerFinalBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(owner);
        console.log("vendor Final Balance", vendorFinalBalance) //vendor Final Balance 0
        console.log("owner Final Balance",ownerFinalBalance) //owner Final Balance 995568878760188160000          
        expect(new BN(ownerFinalBalance))
            .to.be.bignumber.greaterThan(new BN(ownerBalanceBefore));            

        // Check the the owner balance has changed
        expectEvent(txWithdraw, 'ChangeEtherBalance', { value: new BN(vendorBalanceBefore)});
    });
});
```

because that, line

```
expect(new BN(ownerFinalBalance))
        .to.be.bignumber.greaterThan(new BN(ownerBalanceBefore));
```

crash.

I am usign ganache-cli
and
Truffle v5.4.10 (core: 5.4.10)
Solidity - 0.8.7 (solc-js)
Node v16.9.1
Web3.js v1.5.2

Any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: this is just a hunch, but is there any chance _owner address is not that of owner ? 
balance that is being reduced can be explained by gas used in making this transaction

Comment: thanks for the replay. In this case _owner was the sender that call the constructor. But just to be sure and since I am using The Ownable contract from openzeppelin, I replace it _owner with owner(). Same result.

Comment: Maybe it is something related to the testing process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the amount, 257200000000000 to retrieve is smaller than the gas cost that is 84831 * 10000000000 = 8,4831×10^14.